# Segfault when trying to access fields in an object in vector

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

This seems like the most straightforward thing ever, yet it keeps segfaulting no matter what I try. Sorry if it is obvious and easy to search, I've been searching for about 2 hours on countless vector segfault threads, nobody seems to have this exact issue.

```
class A
{
protected:
    std::vector<B> myVector = std::vector<B>(1);
    void doStuff();
};

void A::doStuff()
{
    myVector.push_back(B());
    myVector[0].initiate();
}

class B
{
public:
    int a;
    B();
    void initiate();
};

B::B()
{
}

void B ::initiate()
{
    a = 0; //**this is where segfault happens**
}
```

Also, what if I were to put a vector in B as well? Does the vector of Bs have to completely re-allocate every time I make one of the components have a larger internal vector? Or will that segfault too? In either case, is there a way to allocate a fixed amount of memory per vector slot or something for objects that I expect to grow???

Edit:
"A".h

```
#ifndef PLATE_H
#define PLATE_H

#include "Column.h"
#include <vector>

class World;
class Plate
{
protected:
    World* myWorld;
    std::vector<Column> vColumns = std::vector<Column>(1);
```

"A".cpp:

```
void Plate::initiate(unsigned short xDim, unsigned short yDim, World * world)
{
    myWorld = world;
    dMass = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < xDim; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < yDim; y++) {
            vColumns.push_back(Column());
            std::cout << vColumns.size();
            vColumns[x + y*xDim].initiate(5,myWorld->cMantleDensity,myWorld); //%%%%%%% 5 is temporary
            dMass = dMass + vColumns[x + y*xDim].getDensity() * vColumns[x + y*xDim].getNumGoxels();
        }
    }
}
```

"B".h:

```
#ifndef COLUMN_H
#define COLUMN_H
#include <vector>
#include "Goxel.h"

class World;
class Column
{
protected:
    World* myWorld;
    std::vector<Goxel> vGoxels;
    unsigned char cCrumple;
    unsigned char cVolcanism;
    unsigned short sThickness;
    short sRootDepth;
    float fDensity;
public:
    Column();
    void initiate(unsigned short, unsigned char,World* const);
```

"B".cpp:

```
void Column::initiate(unsigned short thick, unsigned char mantleDensity,World* world)
{
    myWorld = world;
    cCrumple = 0;
    cVolcanism = 0;
    sThickness = thick;
    fDensity = 58; //basalt
    sRootDepth = (short)(-((sThickness * fDensity) / mantleDensity));

    for (int i = 0; i < thick; i++)
    {
        vGoxels.push_back(Goxel());
        vGoxels[i].quickInitiate((char)(((i-1)*58) / 20));
    }
}
```

Comment: What calls B::initiate() when the segfault happens?

Comment: the call in doStuff() to initiate is the culprit. Also, I debugged a cout << myVector.size() the line right above that call, and it returns 1, vectors exists, etc., everything seems fine???

Comment: "Does the vector of Bs have to completely re-allocate every time I make one of the components have a larger internal vector?" No.

Comment: you are missing return type i-e doStuff(); must be void doStuff(); similarly initiate(); must be void initiate();

Comment: @AliKazmi sorry both are void, will edit.  I was simplifying down some irrelevant junk (the problem happens before any of the other junk is parsed at all)

Comment: you consider return types junk? But empty default constructors aren't?

Comment: Also note that you put those classes in reverse order (or maybe copy/pasted them as such). Obviously you haven't tried compiling/running what you posted, because other than the simple syntax errors you'd also see that there is no segfault.

Comment: A segfault at the line you marked would appear when you'd call `initiate` on an invalid object. That's not gonna happen in what you posted, so the error you're seeing is elsewhere and you need to try a debugger.

Comment: A test case which actually compiles is a good thing...

Comment: Is an empty constructor the cause of the issue?  In the actual code, initiate() has arguments I need, which are used for other stuff, which is why it exists. However, I commented all of those out so it looks just like this, and confirm still getting a segfault, so the arguments and other things are not it.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://ideone.com/TCkW2X. I didn't think I would be able to, but I ran it anyway.

Comment: Since you're using C++11 (required for your initialization of `myVector`) then you can declare default constructors like `B() = default;`. In older C++ versions, `B() {}`. No, it's not the source of your problem. It just adds mess.

Comment: i also cant reproduce it

Comment: "However, I commented all of those out so it looks just like this, and confirm still getting a segfault". No, you haven't confirmed it. You tested one thing, then you edited out the problem and posted it here.

Comment: Okay I edited in the relevant actual code

Comment: y = 0, x = 0 at time of segfault, happens on first call to Column.initialize(). Actual stack trace points to whatever the first value set in the Column::initialize() function is. myWorld = world  or cCrumple = 0 if I make that first, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$ gdb a.out
> run
*segfault*
> where
```

The debugger will show you a nice stack trace of where the segfault actually is so that you don't have to guess.

Comment: I do have a stacktrace. It's at myWorld = world (or cCrumple = 0 if I comment out myWorld = world), whatever the first attempt to reach into the actual Column object is.